# UIButton custom background color highlighted and disabled

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have button which is using class customButton. This button function is after 10 touches automatically disable itself.

I have issue with it, on last touch it will take color from isHighlighted and not from isEnabled. How would you fix this?

Many thanks.

```
class customButton: UIButton {
override open var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
      //Set colors for Highlighted & Unhighlighted
        backgroundColor = isHighlighted ? UIColor(named: "RedAlpha")! : UIColor(named: "Red")!
    }
}
override open var isEnabled: Bool {
    didSet {

        backgroundColor = isEnabled ? UIColor(named: "Red")! : UIColor(named: "Dis")!
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the last state change of the button it could have different colour. You can try this.

```
class customButton: UIButton {
    override open var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            updateBackgroundColor()
        }
    }
    override open var isEnabled: Bool {
        didSet {
           updateBackgroundColor()
        }
    }
    func updateBackgroundColor() {
        //Set colors for Highlighted & Unhighlighted
        if isEnabled {
            backgroundColor = isHighlighted ? UIColor(named: "RedAlpha")! : UIColor(named: "Red")!
        } else {
            backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Dis")!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you problem, proper way would be to change the colour of `isEnabled`. But if you want what you've written in question then on last touch set `isHighlighted` to `true` and set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `false` so that it'll ignore user events.

```
customButton.isHighlighted = true
customButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```